# DLL not found while executing the program (c++)

Tags: c++, dll

I created a project which included the headers and lib files and dll's of the Assimp project. I included the lib files in the VS2008 project, and it compiles without errors. I also copy the assimp dll to the output folder, but when I try to run the executable, it says it can't find the Assimp32d.dll.

I have absolutely no idea why the executable can't "see" the dll. What do?

Comment: If you are running via the IDE I _think_ it executes the program in the directory above the output directory. Try copying the DLL up a level.

Comment: The dll file is everywhere as of this point. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: you copied assimp32.dll and it can't find assimp32d.dll ? :)

Comment: Yes. The assimp32.dll is in **every** folder of the project. Including the output folders. Same error.

Comment: assimp32.dll != assimp32 **d** .dll

Comment: Yes. That was the source of my error. The debug dll of assimp of was named assimp32d.dll, and the release was named assimp32.dll. The lib file wanted the dll with the name "assimp32d.dll", or atleast, that is what i think. I just renamed assimp32d.dll to assimp32.dll. Also, I just realized the stupidity of my reply to peenut. I did not notice that extra "d".

Comment: you might find depends.exe to be helpful  you can get it from http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running through MSVS2008 please, check the working directory.

```
property->Debugging->Working Directory // you could access to right button on the project menu.
```

Additionally, check the name of dll.

```
assimp32.dll != assimp32 **d** .dll
```

Additional, you could check if you have all dll accessible to your program with http://www.dependencywalker.com/, just open your exe and seed the dll dependence and if this are accessible or not.

If not all are accessible please copy (dll) or add the dll directory in to the %PATH% variable in

> Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced\Environment
>   Variables

Comment: Yeah, the name of the dll that I copied was wrong (the extra 'd'). The debug dll of assimp of was named assimp32d.dll, and the release was named assimp32.dll. The lib file wanted the dll with the name "assimp32d.dll", or atleast, that is what i think. I just renamed assimp32d.dll to assimp32.dll.